# How do I write/read to a file that I've locked?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm writing a program that is threaded and potentially will run across multiple JVMs. I am having issues with writing and reading to a file once I've locked it (to prevent **other** processes/threads from accessing it). I was originally using a `FileWriter` but nothing was being written to the file.

Now I'm trying an `OutputStream` and for some reason new writes to the file won't append - so only the last entry will appear. What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to read/write to a file once you've locked it?

**Note**: if I delete all the locks and use `FileWriter` combined with `PrintWriter` I don't have these issues so I think my locking mechanism is wrong

```
try {
    // Get a file channel for the file
    File file = new File ( path );
    RandomAccessFile stream = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    FileChannel channel = stream.getChannel();

    // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
    // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();

    OutputStream os = Channels.newOutputStream(channel);

    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(os,true)){
        System.out.println("Writing "  + message);
        pw.println(message);
    }
    os.close();
    // Release the lock - if it is not null!
    if( lock != null ) {
        lock.release();
    }
    stream.close();
    // Close the file
    channel.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler solution would be to use a [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.io.File-boolean-)

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(path, true);
FileChannel channel = os.getChannel();
```

---

When you use

```
new FileWriter(os, true)
```

the `true` mean "append mode" however when you use

```
new PrintWriter(os,true)
```

the `true` means; "flush on newline" i.e. it will always overwrite

When you need to do is to only write from the end of the file. I suggest you use

```
channel.position(channel.size());
```

before you attempt to append.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using FileOutputStream instead now

Comment: But now I'm getting a NonWritableChannelException when I try to lock the `FileInputStream` channel when reading it back in

Comment: @DanaDabbagh for reading you might need RAF, you don't need append mode for reading.

Comment: @DanaDabbagh BTW you might find this project of mine interesting. It does what you want with persisted shared memory but doesn't need a file lock (rarely anyway) https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue

Comment: @Dana Dabbagh: of course, you can’t create a read/write (aka exclusive) lock on a `FileInputStream`. You have to create a read (aka shared) lock instead. But you should consider [opening a `FileChannel` directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) and then direclty [create a `Reader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newReader-java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel-java.lang.String-) or `Writer` for text I/O, instead of hopping through a dozen different APIs…